# How to receive response body via Clever Internet Suite

Tags: delphi

I am having a hard time receiving the response body using Clever Internet Suite. Upon calling the POST request, what do I have to do to receive the response body?

I have tried everything I can, yet only seem to receive the response raw and response headers. Using Fiddler, I receive the response body, I just can't seem to grab it using Clever Internet Suite.

```
procedure ...
var ResponseStream: TStringStream;
begin
  ResponseStream := TStringStream.create;
try
  clHttp.Post(aUrl, clHttpRequest, ResponseStream);
  //clHttp.SendRequest('POST', aUrl, clHttpRequest, ResponseStream);
  Memo.Lines.Add(ResponseStream.DataString); //< Where I see ƒ‘
finally
  ResponseStream.free;
  end;
end;
```

Using a GET request after the POST request to the same URL, it gets the same results as the POST response, for example: `ƒ‘`

Could this be an encoding issue?

Comment: Your `ResponseStream` should be getting the body data. How are you trying to use `ResponseStream` after `Post()`/`SendRequest()` returns? Where exactly are you seeing `ƒ‘`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ResponseStream I have as a TStringStream then loading that into a memo using DataString yet get ƒ‘ as the response.

Comment: I do get a response body when capturing through a proxy but not sure why I receive ƒ‘ on the ResponseStream.

Comment: without seeing the raw HTTP traffic (headers and body), there is really no way to answer this. The code looks fine, provided the encoding of the response body matches the encoding that `TStringStream` expects (which you have to specify in its constructor ahead of time), otherwise the `DataString` won't decode properly. If you used `TMemoryStream` instead, what do the raw bytes look like?

Comment: Getting the size of the TMemoryStream resulted in 546 bytes.

Comment: OK, but what do the *actual bytes* look like? Can you provide a hex dump of, say, the 1st dozen bytes or so?

Comment: With the information you have provided @RemyLebeau I will do some more digging.

Comment: Using BinToHex: 
03910100E47F9BABD3359B6905B0D6B153552CBC7F8910878CA12CC4D2066F82C39EBDD301BBF81E59620135D66505EAD93689966217D2389F297CDEB9E25410B14F7105A77BD7A5698A3FF1E4AC4B5CC19040584BABD64722718E691DB0A0270152E64A14E0062...

Comment: That is NOT textual data, it is binary data, so it makes sense that `TStringStream` would mangle it up (though, I don't see how you can get `ƒ‘` from that data, using a number of different charsets to decode it). What kind of response are you expecting to begin with? What does Clever say the response's `Content-Type` header claims the data to be? You say Fiddler can get the data, what does it look like in Fiddler? And, how exactly did you call `BinToHex()` (to rule out the possibility that you converted the wrong memory by accident)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237908/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-hydroxor).